# nautilus-actions will only create submenus

Tags: 14.04, gnome, nautilus, menu, nautilus-actions

I'd like to edit the "right-click" menu for folders and files.
The recommended tool for the job is [**nautilus-actions**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions) [image: Install nautilus-actions].

However, there are two things this tool cannot do.
1. It can't remove the existing menu items that are already there.

For example,  I am never going to "Email" a directory.  I want to completely remove it from the menu.
[image]

2. When I do use `nautilus-actions`, all of my new menu items show up as sub items of "Nautilus-Actions actions".  I want them to be root menu items.

[image]

Is there an easier way to do all of this?  Where are the configurations stored?  In the registry?  In the filesystem?  Do I have to code something according to the [Nautilus API](https://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/NautilusMenuProvider.html)?

For as simple as this should be, I'm surprised how difficult it has been to find answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the "Nautilus-Actions actions" by going to `Edit->Preferences->Nautilus menu layout`, and changing "Create a root Nautilus-Actions' menu to false.

Comment: That is only answering a small part of your question :) Maybe edit your question if this is what you were looking for.